# How to fix 'Last Login' ... process completed on terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

[image]

I couldt not use command line anymore. how to fix it without re-install macos?

Comment: will you be able to share the content of `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: i'm new macos. how to find this one without using terminal

Comment: you can use [this link](https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks) to show hidden files in finder. go in finder, press `CMD + SHIFT + .` there you will see the file.

Comment: I go to /users/ + cmd +shift + ... I saw a lot files but there is no .bash_profile

Comment: can you please try going into the directory as shown in image https://imgur.com/a/hXnW6Es ? We need to press `CMD + SHIFT + .` inside your user directory.

Comment: yes, I went to go this path /Users/../ + "CMD+SHIFT+." .
I just see .bash_history.
I'm using zsh so now I try to use sh indeed then everything is fine.

Comment: zsh command still not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223501/discussion-between-raghav-garg-and-hoang-lethien).